# Rails - Form accessing items in a db table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms, many-to-many

I'm creating a rails recipe application where when a user is creating a new recipe they have to add ingredients. I have a foods table in the database (there were other attributes about foods that meant I needed another table for it). It needs to be a many-to-many relationship because recipes have multiple ingredients but foods can be in multiple recipes. I created a table, recipes_ingredients, in order to help with this many to many relationship. The problem I am having is in the form for new recipes. The users should only be able to use foods that are in the foods table. I wanted to do the drop-down options that google does on it's searches. It's the best way I could think to do this. Do any of you have ideas for how to do this? Do you have other ideas for how I can add ingredients to recipes?

I'm using rails 4.1, and ruby 2.1. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partial to add the ingredients (take the ingredients from the ingredients table and store it on your recipes_ingredients table).

Add a partial rendering in your recipes form

```
<%= f.fields_for :recipesingredients do |ff| %>
    <ol>
        <table id = "tabla">
            <tr>
                <td style = "padding-left: 8px"><%= render 'recipesingredients_fields', :f => ff %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ol>
<% end %>
<div id = "ingredientsadd"></div>
<%= link_to_add_association 'Add', f, :recipesingredients, 'data-association-insertion-node' => "#ingredientsadd", 'data-association-insertion-method' => "append" %>
```

Then, inside that partial you can add the fields you'd like to add to your recipes_ingredients table. In this case, i assume you'd only need the ingredient_id. In this case, you'd use an options_from_collection tag that'd be fill with the values currently stored in the ingredients table.

```
<%= f.select :ingredient_id , options_from_collection_for_select(@ingredients, :id, :name)%>
```

Keep in mind that your recipes_ingredients needs to have a recipe_id and a ingredient_id field. Also, ingredients must belong_to recipes, and recipes must have_many ingredients.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you. This helps so much! Only a few things to clarify...For some reason the line 
    <%= f.select :ingredient_id , options_from_collection_for_select(@ingredients, :id, :name)%>

is raising an error, "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass"....any idea what that is about?

Comment: That means that the "collection" you are trying to "map" is empty. Do you have any value in the ingredients table? @ingredients (in my example) is supposed to store all the values in the Ingredient model (@ingredients = Ingredient.all).

Comment: I did have ingredients in the table, however I ended up changing how I'm going to do ingredients for my app

Comment: Oh well, if you change it then my provided answer may not be suitable for you anymore. Good luck.